# Сумма массива в C#

Tags: c#

Есть несколько массивов

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 };
int[] array2 = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 };
int[] array3 = { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 };
```

как их добавить и получить один с 15-ти элементов

```
int[] array4 = { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1  };
```

Answer (score 3):

[Enumerable.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb302894.aspx) Объединяет две последовательности:

```
var result = array1.Concat(array2.Concat(array3));
```

Comment: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and no extension method 'Concat' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

использую sharpdevelop, а не VS, это же влияет как-то?

Comment: добавьте ``using System.Linq;``

Answer (score 3):

Наверное, как-то так:

```
int[] array4 = new int[array1.length + array2.length + array3.length];

array1.CopyTo(array4, 0);
array2.CopyTo(array4, array1.length);
array3.CopyTo(array4, array1.length + array2.length);
```